# What is a working setup to use Vim plugins UndoTree and Goyo together?

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows

I love [UndoTree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree), saving me many times when I deleted/rewritten entire paragraphs but days later I realized that I needed to extract a phrase/sentence from them, without completely messing up my current version.

[Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) promotes distraction-free writing but I couldn't figure out how to use them together (without going too deep). I can start UndoTree manually or through the callbacks below but I can't switch to the the UndoTree window. This doesn't seem to be the issue with [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s windows but those are not so closely coupled as the ones opened by UndoTree.

Given enough time I could get into Vim scripting and figure it out but I don't want to (and have the time right now) to reinvent the wheel and it never hurts to ask.

---

**edit**: As a workaround, I have my usual setup with UndoTree panes on the left with the main text in a window next to it, then I fire up Goyo and I can leave it by simply hitting `gt` to make any complicated undo manipulation but this is not ideal.

**edit2**: Fugitive uses `preview-windows` whereas UndoTree uses `:new` with absolute locations (the default is `:topleft vertical`). This absolute positioning causes the issue because opening split windows with any of the commands or with Fzf works just fine.

**dirty solution**:

https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/blob/master/autoload/undotree.vim#L479

```
   1 +--473 lines: =================================================
 478 
 479     " Create undotree window.
 480     if g:undotree_WindowLayout == 1 || g:undotree_WindowLayout == 2                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 481         let cmd = "topleft vertical" .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 482                     \self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 483     else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 484         let cmd = "botright vertical" .                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 485                     \self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 486     endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     --------------------------------------------------------------------
 487     call s:exec("silent keepalt ".cmd)
 493 +----------------------------------------------------------
```

1. Add line `let cmd = 'vertical' . self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname` before `if` block
2. Comment out `if` block

Result:

```
   1 "=================================================
 479     " Create undotree window.
 480     let cmd = 'vertical' . self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 481     " if g:undotree_WindowLayout == 1 || g:undotree_WindowLayout == 2                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 482     "     let cmd = "topleft vertical" .                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 483     "                 \self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 484     " else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 485     "     let cmd = "botright vertical" .                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 486     "                 \self.width . ' new ' . self.bufname                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 487     " endif                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 494     -----------------------------------------------------
```

3. Call `:Goyo 110` in Vim
4. Call `:UndotreeToggle`

Turns out I did have the time.

TODO:

- Clean up and pull request to UndoTree
- Open issue to Goyo (`CTRL-W_CTRL-W` does not work properly with multiple windows)

Comment: those distraction free plugins use autocommands to prevent switching to the surrounding windows. You could either set `eventignore` option or use e.g. `:noa wincmd l`. But you should really open a issue at the goyo plugin to be able to have this fixed.

Comment: I only took a crash course about vimscript since I started this yesterday so thanks for the pointers, I'll look these up. I submitted a pull request to the UndoTree repo to allow setting up custom positioning commands and the changes work with Goyo perfectly. `CTRL-W_CTRL-W` is a no go but `CTRL-W [hjkl]` work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UndoTree layouts use absolute positioning commands by default (`topleft`,`botright`) but it can be configured to accept custom ones.

My `.vimrc` setup:

```
" === UndoTree
" using relative positioning instead
let g:undotree_CustomUndotreeCmd = 'vertical 32 new'
let g:undotree_CustomDiffpanelCmd= 'belowright 12 new'

" === Goyo
" changing from the default 80 to accomodate for UndoTree panel
let g:goyo_width = 104

" to automatically start UndoTree and Limelight when firing up Goyo
" (see more in Goyo project repo)
function! s:goyo_enter()
  Limelight0.7
  UndotreeToggle
  " ...
endfunction

function! s:goyo_leave()
  Limelight!
  UndotreeToggle
  " ...
endfunction

autocmd! User GoyoEnter nested call <SID>goyo_enter()
autocmd! User GoyoLeave nested call <SID>goyo_leave()
```

[image]

Comment: Just noting here because you are apparently too modest to do so that the custom commands you describe only exist in UndoTree because you wrote code to add them :).

Comment: If these guys hadn't written these plugins, I would still be stuck in Vim stone age. Thanks though (and also thank you for creating the proper tags:)